# What are C++ non-template members as used in the Barton-Nackman trick?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, templates

From wikipedia:

```
// A class template to express an equality comparison interface.
template<typename T> class equal_comparable
{
    friend bool operator==(T const &a, T const &b) { return  a.equal_to(b); }
    friend bool operator!=(T const &a, T const &b) { return !a.equal_to(b); }
};

class value_type
// Class value_type wants to have == and !=, so it derives from
// equal_comparable with itself as argument (which is the CRTP).
     : private equal_comparable<value_type>
{
public:
    bool equal_to(value_type const& rhs) const; // to be defined
};
```

This is supposed to be the [Barton-Nackman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton-Nackman_trick), that could achieve compile-time dimensional analysis (checking if some operations applied to variables end up in comparable numbers, like speed comparable to space/time but no acceleration).

Could anyone explain me how, or at least explain me what are the NON-TEMPLATE members?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules of the language have changed since the pattern was invented, although care was taken not to break it. In other words, as far as I can tell, it still works but for different reasons than it originally did. I don't think I would base an attempt at dimensional analysis on this pattern as I think there are better ways of doing that today.

I also think the example is too trivial to be helpful. As already stated the instantiation of `equal_comparable<value_type>` causes `operator==` and `operator!=` for `value_type` to appear. Since they are non-members it doesn't matter that the inheritance is private, they're still eligable for selection when resolving a call. It's just hard to see the point in this example. Let's say however, that you add a template parameter to `equal_comparable` and a few other things:

```
template<typename U, typename V> class equal_comparable
{
    friend bool operator==(U const &a, V const &b) { return  a.equal_to(b); }
    friend bool operator!=(U const &a, V const &b) { return !a.equal_to(b); }
};

class some_other_type 
{
    bool equal_to(value_type const& rhs) const;
};

class value_type
: private equal_comparable<value_type>,      // value_type comparable to itself
  private equal_comparable<some_other_type>  // value_type comparable to some_other_type
{
public:
    bool equal_to(value_type const& rhs) const;
    bool equal_to(some_other_type const& rhs) const;
};
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea if this is the way it's *supposed* to be used but I'm reasonably sure that it would work as described.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

These are actually nontemplate nonmembers - the comparison operators in the base template - they get used by the ADL for the derived class. A template member would be something like:

```
class C
{
    ...
    template < typename T > void DoGreatStuff( T t ) { ... }
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The instantiation of `equal_comparable<value_type>` in `value_type` class causes the compiler to generate two comparison functions:

```
friend bool operator==(value_type const &a, value_type const &b) { return  a.equal_to(b); }
friend bool operator!=(value_type const &a, value_type const &b) { return !a.equal_to(b); }
```

These functions are nontemplate since they do not depend on any template parameter, but they are also nonmembers since they are declared as `friend`.